# CSS Grid nested in a wrapper-div or a body element?

Tags: css, css-grid

In this series they all used a wrapper div.

[MDN - CSS GRID Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Is this necessary, and if yes, why?

Comment: all depend if you will have more content on the body or not

Comment: Ok, for whole page layout there is no reason to not use the body-element as the grid-container. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purposes of wrappers are several, including:

- to group elements semantically, for instance to separate page heading
  from body text from sidebar from footer.
- to group elements cosmetically, such as with a surrounding border or
  a common background image or color.
- to group elements in layout, such as to keep them all in the same
  column when columns are floated next to one another.
- to enable special positioning, as when a wrapper is given relative
  positioning in order to contain child elements with absolute
  positioning.
- to make it more convenient to specify elements in CSS and JavaScript
  by referring to their parent, without having to id or class each
  child element.

(Note: the var above should all be on one line)

So in this case, i think they all used a wrapper div just to group elements in layout.